# Server Side Field validation in .NET Core 3.1 MVC in modal popup not working

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a partial view within a modal popup. Client side field validation works, such as required fields. But there are some server side validations that don't present themselves whilst keeping the modal popup open.

For example, I create a new 'teacher band' and the controller checks for a duplicate band. When I press submit, the page actually browses to the partial view and presents the error in the validationsumary, rather than keeping it within the modal.

Controller -

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Add()
    {
        CreateTeacherBandViewModel model = new CreateTeacherBandViewModel();
        return PartialView(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Add(CreateTeacherBandViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (await _teacherBandService.BandExists(model.BandName))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "A band with that name already exists");

                return PartialView(model);
            }
            else
            {
                await _teacherBandService.Add(model);

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "TeacherBand", null);
            }

        }
        else
        {
            return PartialView();
        }
    }
```

Partial View

```
@model Models.CreateTeacherBandViewModel

<script src="~/assets/js/plugins/pickers/color/spectrum.js"></script>

<script src="~/assets/js/demo_pages/picker_color.js"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Add", "TeacherBand", null))
{
<!-- Iconified modal -->
<div id="modal_addband" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog  modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header bg-primary text-white">
                <h5 class="modal-title"><i class="icon-user-plus mr-2"></i> Add New Band</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Name</label>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.BandName, new { @class = "form-control"})
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BandName)
                </div>

                <h6 class="font-weight-semibold">Charge Rates</h6>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>AM</label>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DefaultChargeRateAM, new { @class = "form-control"})
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DefaultChargeRateAM)
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>PM</label>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DefaultChargeRatePM, new { @class = "form-control"})
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DefaultChargeRatePM)
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Daily</label>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DefaultChargeRateDaily, new { @class = "form-control"})
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DefaultChargeRateDaily)
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <h6 class="font-weight-semibold">Pay Rates</h6>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>AM</label>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DefaultPayRateAM, new { @class = "form-control"})
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DefaultPayRateAM)
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>PM</label>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DefaultPayRatePM, new { @class = "form-control"})
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DefaultPayRatePM)
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Daily</label>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DefaultPayRateDaily, new { @class = "form-control"})
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DefaultPayRateDaily)
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <hr />

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Colour</label>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Colour, new { @class = "form-control"})
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Colour)
                </div>
```

@Html.ValidationSummary()

```
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create Band</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /iconified modal -->

<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"> 
</script>
}
```

Finally, the Index page that renders the partial view

```
@Html.Partial("Add", new CreateTeacherBandViewModel())
```

Comment: Im assuming that you have attributes on your class variables? Lets see the class

Comment: Did you uesd the [Required]Attribute on the BandName property and your BandName property is non-null type like int,float，
Then you inserted 0 to test the code. If my conjecture is right，please use [BindRequired] Attribute instead of [Required] Attribute, or use int?,float? instead of int,float